# youtube height and width on iframe wont work

Tags: html, css, iframe

So i followed this video tutorial to make my iframe video responsive to mobile or any other device

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X4t0JxiBeO0

and they have said to add this to the iframe code

```
<div class="iframe-container">
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Bey4XXJAqS8" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
</iframe></div>
```

after doing this, they said to add the following code

```
.iframe-container {
max-width: 100%;
height: 0;
margin-top: 60px;
padding-bottom: 56.25%;
position: relative;
}

.iframe-container iframe {
position: absolute;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
left: 0;
right: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Now the only issue that I have is that the width and height in the iframe html code doesnt seem to work and its covering 100% of the width and not using the width and height I assigned it to turn into, but it is responsive but I want it to be smaller and not as big

now I have tried everything such as increasing and decreasing the padding bottom and all of that, but it doesnt seem to work. Is there a fix to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for previous answer.

I would do this by adding second container.

```html
<div class="iframe-container">

   <div class="iframe-container-2">
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Bey4XXJAqS8" frameborder="0"
         allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
   </div>

</div>
```

```css
.iframe-container {
   width: 500px;
}

.iframe-container-2 {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   height: 0;
   padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}

iframe {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
}
```

Comment: I dont want to remove them, I want to use them but they dont seem to be working which is odd.

Comment: I mean removing the inline attributes, note the one in the style sheet.

Comment: now the video wont be responsive, i dont understand how its working in the video

Comment: thank you for trying to help, now I have tried this, its responsive but it still has the issue.

Comment: Try using the exact code, and changing the first container to the size you prefer.

Comment: turns out, you messed up on the first code but then edited it and it worked! thanks alot